# Datepicker Can't take Today's Date

Tags: datetime, xamarin, xamarin.forms, datepicker

I'm developing a report page that it works accourding to date. I want to show some information between 2 dates. I have a datepicker to select date but when user want to select today ( I mean DateTime.Now) "DateSelected" event does not fire. I close popup in this dateselected event and date not update so user can not select it.
Sorry for my English but I try to tell.

```
 private async void queryDatePicker_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
    }
```

ViewModel :

```
private DateTime _mDate = DateTime.Now;

    public DateTime MDate
    {
        get { return _mDate; }
        set
        {
            _mDate = value;
           
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_mDate));


            string queryParameter = Preferences.Get("queryParameters", "");
            string pid = reportsParameters.PID;
            string output = _mDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            queryParameter += output + pid + ";;";
            Preferences.Set("queryParameters", queryParameter);
            Console.WriteLine(queryParameter);




            
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<DatePicker Margin="0, 20, 0, 0" Date="{Binding MDate}"  DateSelected="queryDatePicker_DateSelected"  x:Name="queryDatePicker" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium"  BackgroundColor="#4DC6C7" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem and there is a known issue on the github that has the same problem as yours. You can check [DatePicker don't trigger event when current date is selected](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13162).

And according to the official document about the [DatePicker.DateSelected Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.datepicker.dateselected?view=xamarin-forms):

> An event fired when the Date property changes

So it will not be fired if the date value doesn't change. For a workaround, you can use the UnFocused event instead of the DateSelected event. It will trigger when user selects a date.

Comment: This is a great idea. I'm trying now.

Comment: This is the solution! Great idea. Thank you Liyun Zhang - MSFT

Comment: You welcome. Happy coding!